# two jQuery functions listening to the same button click but only one works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code for the first function(keeping in mind its tested and it works fine):

```
$('.create-invoice').on('click',function()
{   

    grab_invoice_data();
    // Declare a variable
    var jsonObj = invoice_data;

    // Lets convert our JSON object
    var postData = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

    // Lets put our stringified json into a variable for posting
    var postArray = {json:postData};

    //if cookie exists
    var i_n = $('.inv-number').val();
    $.cookie('lid', ++i_n, { expires: 365 } ); 
    //invoices created
    if( $.cookie('ic') ){
    var ck_inv_created = ($.cookie('ic'));
    $.cookie('ic', (++ck_inv_created));
    } else {
    $.cookie('ic', ++inv_created);
    }
})
```

Code for the second function(it works perfectly. this is the newly added function):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".reloadpg").click(function(){
    $.get("http://localhost/einvoice/inum.php", function(data) {
        $(".on input").val(data);
    });  
});
});
```

The problem is that when i placed the second function in my code it worked but the first function stopped from working! keeping in mind they listen to the same button.. so get disparate and tried to do this code:

```
$('.create-invoice').on('click',function()
{   

    grab_invoice_data();
    // Declare a variable
    var jsonObj = invoice_data;

    // Lets convert our JSON object
    var postData = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

    // Lets put our stringified json into a variable for posting
    var postArray = {json:postData};
       //Below is the code i added from the second function to the first its not working here.. when     it was alone outside this function it will worked but it won't here

    $.download("php/json.php", postArray, 'post');
     $.get( "/einvoice/inum.php", function(data) {
        $('.inv-number').val(data);
    });
//Above is the code i added from the second function..
//below is the rest of the code for the function which was there from the beginning, keep in mind only the below code is bing executed the above is not.. its not refreshing the part of the page it should its calling the php script successfully tho, but i will have to refresh the page my self to see the number updated 

    //if cookie exists
    var i_n = $('.inv-number').val();
    $.cookie('lid', ++i_n, { expires: 365 } ); 
    //invoices created
    if( $.cookie('ic') ){
    var ck_inv_created = ($.cookie('ic'));
    $.cookie('ic', (++ck_inv_created));
    } else {
    $.cookie('ic', ++inv_created);
    }
})
```

i need both function to work successfully when the button is clicked not just one! any help would be  appreciated

Comment: Side note - why are you using `on` instead of `click`? `on` takes a lot more processing power since it has to watch things globally instead of just a particular element.

Comment: @jraede `click` it's a shortcut for `on`, in fact `on` allows you to pass an additional selector which is useful to watch for click events inside a long list (see http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/click/ the documentation clearly mentions that `click` is a shortcut)

Comment: Silly question... `.create-invoice` and `.reloadpg` points to the same button? You mention that on the question, but they are different classes... it was a typo in the answer?

Comment: The code from the second function you pasted into the first one looks different from the original version. It contains a reference to `$.download` (probably a plugin, since it's not a standard jQuery function), which is not there in your second function. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Diego ill explain to you, first i tried to use .create-invoice for both functions but still the problem was there so i added another value in the class of the html button now it looks like this:  <button id="Refresh" class="create-invoice btn-large btn-primary reloadpg" >Create invoice</button> it works for each function separately or i can use a single one for both as i learned.

Comment: @StefanoDalpiaz what happened was that i did cut that part of the code -    $.download("php/json.php", postArray, 'post'); - for the first function then i pasted it back for the second, but it is originally in the function i just did that by mistake. This solved my problem though! i never gave attention to this line but you made me look at it and i tried to pot it inside the second function and it solved my problem! . please post this and an answer so i can accept it. ps: the code looks like the last bloke in my question but the $.download line is inside the function below it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call the second function from the first.

```
$('.create-invoice').click(function(){
    secondFunction();
    //rest of code
});

var secondFunction = function(){
    //code
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is that you accidentally inserted a line which was not meant to be there:

```
$.download("php/json.php", postArray, 'post');
```

Just remove this line and it should all work.

Comment: $.get( "/einvoice/inum.php", function(data) {
          $.download("php/json.php", postArray, 'post');
         $('.inv-number').val(data);  }); right code is like this bro